# Entity Manager - create query - nested select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm trying to execute the next:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT processId FROM (SELECT processId FROM table_name WHERE processName like '%abcaccz%')")
```

But I'm getting:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.
unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 23
```

What is missing here? (This is working in my db client area).

Comment: Try adding an alias after the closing paren.

Comment: Example, please? Anyway, also this fails: em.createQuery("SELECT processId FROM (SELECT processId FROM table_name WHERE processName like '%abcaccz%') a")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT processId = (SELECT processId FROM table_name WHERE processName like '%abcaccz%') FROM table_name")
```

or:

```
em.createQuery("
  SELECT processId
    FROM table_name
    WHERE processId IN (SELECT processId
                           FROM table_name
                           WHERE processName like '%abcaccz%')")
```